# Accessing second display over first monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop, projector

I got and projector on my computer which totaly works fine. I can move windows back and forth with keybinds and what not. 
Usually thats all I need but sometimes I need to interact. Like clicking somewhere in the window. The problem is that I don't see the output of the projector since it is in another room. And changing the display settings to "clone" instead of "extend" all the times doesn't work really well.
I tried using virtual desktops, but non of them can do what I need.

So does anybody know, how I can see and interact with my second screen just like I would do with an virtual desktop?

I really hope someone had this problem already.

Cheers.

Comment: What about finding a cheap/old monitor laying about somewhere, and set it up either with an external cloner or clone it with the projector on your PC. An external one sounds like a better bet as you can take the monitor out any time when you're not using it.

Comment: A third monitor would be a solution but I already used all the ports on the graphics card. I might need an Y connector or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a different solution: when you're in the room with the projector, run a 'remote mouse/keyboard' app on a smartphone or tablet to control your PC. Then you can sit in front of the projector and when you need to click, pull out your smartphone/tablet and use it to move the mouse and click on whatever you need.

As an alternative to a 'remote mouse/keyboard' app, you could use an app that lets you view the PC's screen remotely (and use the mouse/keyboard remotely), but that would be overkill because you can already see the screen when you're in the room with the projector.

So the idea is to make your mouse/keyboard accessible from another room instead of making your second screen accessible from another room.